# jTable connected to MySQL button error

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, jtable

i have the following jframe :

[image]

and i wanna make the buttons work im still new to programming can someone help me please? i want the add row btn to add a new row to database, the update btn let me save changes and delete delete the selected row, also the jTextBoxes are connected to the database
i tried doing this to update :

```html
Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement pst = null; 
        try{
    String value1=txt_cid.getText();
    String value2=txt_carid.getText();
    String value3=txt_aid.getText();
    String value4=txt_rd.getText();
    String value5=txt_bd.getText();
    String value6=txt_bn.getText();
    
    String sql="update booking set customer_id'"+value1+"',car_id'"+value2+"',agency_id'"+value3+"',return_date'"+value4+"',booking_date'"+value5+"',booking_number'"+value6+"',";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "table updated");
}catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

but it didnt work out for me i get exception error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't stated what the error is but `UPDATE` takes an equals operator for every parameter. Also use `PreparedStatement` placeholders to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks:

```
String sql = "update booking set customer_id=?, car_id=?,agency_id=?,return_date=?,booking_date=?,booking_number=?";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setInt(1, value1);
pst.setInt(2, value2);
... // set the other parameters
```

Read: [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: could you please be a little more specific im very new to programming :/

Comment: Check out the link to UPDATE syntax just posted

Comment: Read [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html) before you go any further

Comment: i must create the pst inside my jFrame?

Comment: Forget about the frame. Just get the `JDBC` working on its without any GUI code

Comment: im sorry if this is too much to ask for you but could you possibly help me via teamviewer please?

Comment: I don't have time for that but follow the approach given in the answer in a stripped down version of your application, i.e. no GUI